# I am changing a variable in a list and I am trying to get the reset after each loop

Tags: python, loops

```
for num in range(len(boards)):
    boards[num] = boards[num] - move[1]
    print(boards)
    if xor(boards) == 0:
        winningMoves.append((boards[num], move[1]))
```

Basically I have a list of piles and I am removing stuff from them. However after each iteration the list stays the same if it was altered. How can I ensure that the list goes back to original after each iteration?

Comment: It's the same `list`, why would you expect it *not* to change? You are going to have to work with a *copy* of the list if you don't want to affect the original list.

Comment: Well what I am saying is I want the original list that contains piles to be altered and then the function applied to it. Then if the result equals 0 it will append it to a winning move list. Then I want to go to the next pile in original list and have the first pile revert back to the original as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
for num in range(len(boards)):
    boards[num] = boards[num] - move[1]
    if xor(boards) == 0:
        winningMoves.append((boards[num], move[1]))
        boards[num] = boards[num] + move[1]
```

Ended up just adding number back to list after appending it. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Another option is to save the value of `board[num]` before you change it so you can restore it after the test.

Comment: Why are you only reverting it if it's a winning move?

Answer (score -1):

To reset the list, you must either recreate it, or store it as a tmp variable.

In this case, I have decided to store it as a tmp variable.

```
tmpBoard={}
for key in boards.keys():
   tmpBoard[key]=boards[key]
for num in range(len(boards)):
    boards[num] = boards[num] - move[1]
    print(boards)
    if xor(boards) == 0:
        winningMoves.append((boards[num], move[1]))
        borads=tmpBoard #<-- reset list
```

Please note that the previous answer had the mistake of having`tmpBoard=boards`, which is wrong because in such a case an update done to boards will also appear on tmpBoard. In this alternative case, tmpBoard is not a **coy** of boards, but a new variable.

Comment: This is incorrect. Python assignment *does not make copies*.

Comment: is that better?

Comment: No. Assignment **does not make copies in Python** after the first iteration, you keep working with the same object. Also, in the question I'm pretty sure boards was a list... And you should use `for key in some_dict` not `for key in some_dict.keys()`

Comment: No. boards is a list so it doesn't have keys. And you have a typo "borads". Just save `boards[num]`.

Comment: There's also another typo "coy"

Comment: Please read: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder

Comment: I haven't downvoted yet, but you need to fix this answer.